# Accessibility: show content in modal on small devices, show content inline on large devices

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, accessibility, client-hints

I need to show certain content in a modal/fullscreen panel on small devices, triggered by a button. On large devices, this same content, is just always shown and the trigger is then hidden.

How do you approach this for accessibility?

Currently, I have this setup

```
<button type="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="filter-panel">Filter</button>

<div class="o-panel" id="filter-panel">Form</div>
```

Initially, the `o-panel` is hidden on small devices via CSS (in a media query that targets small devices). I set `aria-expanded` to true when the trigger is hit, and add an `active` class to the panel itself, which shows the fullscreen `o-panel` via CSS. On large devices, I hide the button and always display the content from `o-panel` via CSS (in a media query that targets large devices), inline, where it is found in the HTML.

Does this make sense for accessibility? My panel doesn't say `role="dialog"`, becuase on large devices it's just content, not a dialog. Is it a problem that my button is hidden on these large devices?

I'm really stuck at what I should do here. If I add `role="dialog"` to my o-panel, should I remove this property for large devices, where it is actually not a modal?

Or should I move copy/move the content from my `o-panel` in a div with `role="dialog"`, in case the trigger is hit? I just don't want two copies of the same content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On large devices you need to do a couple of things.

### Hide the button properly

First make sure the button is `display:none`, not `visibility:hidden` or anything else or it will still show up in the accessibility tree.

### The main (`<main>`) problem

A modal should appear outside of your `<main>`.

This is so you can add `aria-hidden="true"` to the `<main>` element when the modal is active, so as to stop people navigating outside of the modal on a screen reader. (Screen reader users use headings, links etc. to navigate a page so you can't just intercept the <kbd>tab</kbd> key.)

Now I come from a mobile first philosophy so I would say your markup should be mobile first. That means putting the modal outside of your `<main>` as discussed earlier.

This obviously causes a huge problem on a desktop. You now have the content sat somewhere it shouldn't be.

Because of this you only really have two options here.

#### Option 1

Use JavaScript to reposition the modal content in a predefined placeholder `<div>`.

So you keep your mobile first design, then use JavaScript to find the `innerHTML` of your modal and move it into the body within your holder. Then delete the modal itself just to be sure.

While you are at it I would also delete the button, just in case someone resizes the screen to a mobile view, we don't want a button leading nowhere.

Alternatively don't delete the second content then people can resize the browser, just means a few extra DOM nodes (so as long as your modal content isn't over 100 DOM elements I would say do this.)

If you decide to keep the modal make sure that is **also** `display: none` for the same reason as the button, we don't want people accidentally accessing it.

#### Option 2

Duplicate content.

I know, **I know**, duplicate content is just, urgh.

But sometimes you just have to put up with it if it is for the best.

By duplicating the content into a div from the start you do get a few advantages.

**Advantages**

1. If the user resizes the screen you can just use CSS to switch between views.
2. No need for JavaScript, great for if your site functions without JS or **when** your JavaScript fails.
3. Although it adds page weight it is likely to be better for performance overall, the potential for layout shifts with the first option resulting in a high [Cumulative Layout Shift](https://web.dev/cls/) is quite high (although avoidable). With Google putting so much emphasis on [Web Vitals](https://web.dev/vitals/) I would start considering them now. Additionally you might find you write nearly as much JavaScript as there is HTML if your modal only contains a couple of elements.

**Disadvantages**

1. You would have extra page weight due to duplicated HTML.
2. You may have to adjust scripts etc. to account for the second duplicate item (although this should be minor).

**This would still be my preference, Keep It Simple! This is far more robust**

#### Option 3 (for the future)

[Client Hints](https://caniuse.com/client-hints-dpr-width-viewport) are one way you could solve this, turning responsive design into a hybrid of mobile vs desktop and responsive.

When client hints has enough of a market share you could simply use the header to decide which version of the page to send from the initial request.

You could possibly implement this today if you are willing for 25% of users to see the mobile version of your information on desktop, depends how important the info is.

### Other considerations

There are a few other things to consider that you haven't mentioned so I thought I would add for reference.

I already mentioned adding `aria-hidden` to all elements outside of the modal when it is active.

To future proof your application use [`inert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/inert) on items outside of the modal. [Support isn't great (none existent!)](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_htmlelement_inert), but every little helps and it is quite likely to get implemented!

You can polyfill it if you want but I don't think it has moved outside of the draft spec yet so we just use it as is.

Also add `aria-modal="true"` to your modal.

I covered a lot of these points in a bit [more detail in this answer if you want a bit more info.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62690413/2702894)

Comment: Oh dear, that's a lot to take into account! Thanks for this clear overview and options. Note sure I have the time on my current project for all this though. Regarding Option 2 (duplicate content), I can then hide/show the content on desktop/mobile via CSS, that's no issue?

How does this match with for example headers and doormats? Where in mobile the menu is a fullscreen menu behind a hamburger, and doormats in desktop slide in on mobile. Should this then also be dialogs?

Comment: Yes that is fine, just ensure you set `display:none` in your CSS on the button and modal on desktop and vice versa on mobile.  Mobile navigation is a little different, they should use `aria-haspopup="true"`, `aria-controls="id"` on the button and have a `<nav>` element with that ID on a mobile. A bit much to put in a comment but generally with a menu you can get away with the same markup and just removing a couple of attributes and hiding the menu button on desktop so no need for duplicate content there if you design the menu correctly.

Comment: I work on large CMS based projects, with component based page configuration. Is it still valid to render the dialog inside the component itself, and then when the user clicks the button, move the dialog element outside the <main> element? Or should this happen on page load?

Comment: Hmmm interesting question, ideally I would say on page load as in within the original HTML. You could potentially have a function that moves all dialogs outside of the `<main>`. Then call this function after all important assets have loaded on page load. Additionally call this function if a modal button is clicked. Then it is just a simple task of having a gobal flag "all dialogs moved" so you don't waste compute time if it got called after all assets were loaded and you click on a modal dialog launch button (or if called previously by clicking a modal launch button). Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Thanks. There's lots of info on accessibility, but it is sometimes confusing. Some tutorials never mention moving dialogs outside <main>. For me it'll be easier to move a dialog outside main after all components have been loaded, thus on DOMContentLoaded.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` in your `<head>` tag.
Then in your style, you can play around with

```css
@media only screen and (max-width:620px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  
  }
```

You can learn more about the `@media` rule here: [W3Schools Media Rule](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp).

If you have any more questions be sure to ask!

Comment: Sorry that this was not clear, I do this already with media queries. That is not the issue. My question is mainly a11y focused: what should I do with a panel that is in small devices a dialog, but in large devices just content.

Comment: You could use JavaScript and call a function Dialog() on smaller devices, and Content() on larger devices.

Answer (score 0):

The accessibilitys properties are only aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="filter-panel" don't change it.

Your class and ID names doesn't have any impact on accessibility.

If you only want to show the content by default on large device, and display a call to action to show it only on smartphone device, you could do that with javascript and media-query.